# fabric.js straight line and select on click

Tags: fabricjs

I made 3 modes for this code:

1. select line
2. draw line and
3. delete line.

It looks like it is working. But I want to change 2 things.
For example that every time when I select a line i just need to click it.

Can you tell me how i can improve my code ?

Thank You for your answers.

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type ="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
 <script type ="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="select">Selection mode</button>
<button id="draw">Drawing mode</button>

<button id="delete">Delete selected object(s)</button><br />
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
var line, isDown,mode;

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

$("#select").click(function(){
    mode="select";   
         canvas.selection=true;
     canvas.perPixelTargetFind = true;
     canvas.targetFindTolerance = 4;
     canvas.renderAll();
});
$("#draw").click(function(){
    
     
    mode="draw";
});
$("#delete").click(function(){
    
    
    deleteObjects();
});

// Adding objects to the canvas...

 
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
  isDown = true;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  var points = [ pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y ];
   
  if(mode=="draw"){
    line = new fabric.Line(points, {
    strokeWidth: 5,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'red',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',

  });
  canvas.add(line);}
});
 
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
  if (!isDown) return;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  
  if(mode=="draw"){
  line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
  canvas.renderAll(); }
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
  isDown = false;
});

  

// select all objects
function deleteObjects(){
    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject(),
    activeGroup = canvas.getActiveGroup();
    if (activeObject) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            canvas.remove(activeObject);
        }
    }
    else if (activeGroup) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            var objectsInGroup = activeGroup.getObjects();
            canvas.discardActiveGroup();
            objectsInGroup.forEach(function(object) {
            canvas.remove(object);
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ps.: Sorry for bad english or mistakes.

Answer (score 9):

When adding a line to canvas it is normally selectable.
But since you modified it's own properties like width and height that derives from the 2 points, its widht and height are changed.

If you change dimensions programmatically you have to call `line.setCoords()` explicitly otherwise the interaction points are not calculated again.

perPixelTargetFind is optional and does not need to be called every time you go on selection mode.

So the answer is:

call line.setCoords() in your mouseup event.

Check the snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type ="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
 <script type ="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="select">Selection mode</button>
<button id="draw">Drawing mode</button>

<button id="delete">Delete selected object(s)</button><br />
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
var line, isDown,mode;

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
     canvas.perPixelTargetFind = true;
     canvas.targetFindTolerance = 4;

$("#select").click(function(){
    mode="select";   
    canvas.selection=true;
    canvas.renderAll();
});
$("#draw").click(function(){
    
     
    mode="draw";
});
$("#delete").click(function(){
    
    
    deleteObjects();
});

// Adding objects to the canvas...

 
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
  isDown = true;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  var points = [ pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y ];
   
  if(mode=="draw"){
    line = new fabric.Line(points, {
    strokeWidth: 5,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'red',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',

  });
  canvas.add(line);}
});
 
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
  if (!isDown) return;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  
  if(mode=="draw"){
  line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
  canvas.renderAll(); }
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
  isDown = false;
  line.setCoords();
});

  

// select all objects
function deleteObjects(){
    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject(),
    activeGroup = canvas.getActiveGroup();
    if (activeObject) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            canvas.remove(activeObject);
        }
    }
    else if (activeGroup) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            var objectsInGroup = activeGroup.getObjects();
            canvas.discardActiveGroup();
            objectsInGroup.forEach(function(object) {
            canvas.remove(object);
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your code where you create the line you can change it to below so that you can select the line when you click on it

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmachan/L10ren1q/)

```
  if(mode=="draw"){
line = new fabric.Line(points, {
strokeWidth: 5,
fill: 'red',
stroke: 'red',
originX: 'center',
originY: 'center',
selectable: true,
targetFindTolerance: true
}
```